# configurar dns en pod de kubernetes

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

buenas tardes. tengo un problema con una arquitectura multi-tenant que estoy montando en kubernetes. la misma consta de dos pods(front y back), el front le pega a una url que apunta al backend y en el back tengo los diferentes clientes(tenants) que tengo.
el config del nginx del back esta definido de la siguiente manera:

```
server_name ~^(?<account>.+)\-backend.domain\.com$;
  root /var/www/html/tenant/$account-backend/;
  index index.php;
```

esto significa que si quiero llegar al backend desde el front seria con una url como esta: tenant1.backend.domain.com

el front esta expuesto con un servicio tipo nodeport y un balanceador de carga
el backend esta expuesto a nivel local con un servicio de tipo ClusterIP que es el siguiente:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-clusterip-app-backend
  namespace: app
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: app-nginx
```

al momento de subir el cluster e ir al front y realizar una petición, el pod no puede resolver  el tenant1.backend.domain.com. he intentando configurando a través de coredns unas reglas de re direccionamiento, pero no entiendo muy bien como funciona:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:  
  name: coredns-custom  
  namespace: kube-system 
data:
  zoomcrm.server: |
    tenant1.backend.domain.com {
      forward . service-clusterip-app-backend:80
    }
```

básicamente lo que requiero es que el front sepa que hacia donde debe ir cuando la url de la solicitud sea tenant1.backend.domain.com. he indagado sobre el tema pero nada de lo que he realizado me ha funcionado

Comment: Has intentado poner un ingress en el backend y desde el frontend paserle unas cabeceras con el tenant?

Answer (score 0):

Cómo menciona loki, Ingress es la mejor opción de esa manera puedes configurarlo para apuntar a un servicio que está asociado al deployment.

```
Inconming request -> ingress -> front / back
```

podría configurarlo de manera que si hay un request a:

tudominio.com -> frontend
api.tudominio.com -> backend

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: tu-namespace
  name: nombre-para-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: tu-ip #esta ip estará asociada al load balancer que se genera al usar ingress
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: certificate # puedes crear un certificado manejado en el mismo cluster
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: tudominio.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: tu-servicio
                port:
                  number: 8000
    - host: api.tudominio.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: tu-otro-servicio
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

Este ejemplo está usando ingres GKE (de google): https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress

Pero vas a encontrar una implementación específica para cada cloud provider, por ejemplo en amazon usan utilizan este: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html